# Router Guards canActivate not working with API in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, api, canactivate

This  Auth guard not working with API  response.  When I run the code it always returns true. but I want to run guard base on api response. is their way to achieving that?

```js
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot, Router, Route} from '@angular/router';
import {
    HttpClient,
    HttpHeaders
} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

    constructor(private router: Router, private http: HttpClient) {
    }

    canActivate(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {

        const sendData = {};
        sendData['id'] = sessionStorage.getItem('id');
        console.log(JSON.stringify(sendData));
        const headers = new HttpHeaders()
            .set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
            .set('token', sessionStorage.getItem('auth') ? sessionStorage.getItem('auth') : 'test');
        this.http.post('http://127.0.0.1:5000/auth',
            JSON.stringify(sendData), {
                headers
            })
            .subscribe(
                (val: any) => {
                },
                response => {

                    this.router.navigate(['/login']);
                },
                () => {
                    console.log('The POST observable is now completed.');
                });

        return true;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Check this. You have returned true at the end of the **canActivate** authguard. This way it will always return true. Instead you should have it in the subscribe method of the http post request based on your condition. Something like this..

```
this.http.post('http://127.0.0.1:5000/auth',
JSON.stringify(sendData), {
    headers
}).pipe(map(response => {
    //suppose we get isAuthenticated bit in response. Your response obj may vary but logic shall be same
    if (response.isAuthenticated) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}));
```

Thanks.

Comment: Good  Sir how I delay canActivate return. because   API call gets some time to respond.

Comment: As canActivate can return an Observable<boolean> or Promise<boolean> you don't need to worry about delay. If at all you want, you can hook to subscribe method of http post.